# Prove that deSitter-Schwarzschild metric with constant Ricci scalar is Einstein

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, curvature

**Reference: [this paper page 4](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5511)**

**Prove that the following metric is Einstein**

Given deSitter-Schwarzschild metric with mass $m > 0$ and scalar Ricci $R=2$ by

\begin{align}
 \bigg( 1-\frac{r^2}{3}-\frac{2m}{r} \bigg)^{-1} dr^2 + r^2 g_{\Bbb S^2}
\end{align}

where $g_{\Bbb S^2} = d\theta^2 + \text{sin}^2 \theta\ d\phi^2$.

**Proof.**

\begin{align}
 R_{11} =\ & \Lambda g_{11}
 \nonumber\\
 %
 %
    \Lambda =\ & -\frac{2m}{r^3} + \frac{2}{3} \tag{1}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
R_{22} =\ & \Lambda g_{22}
\nonumber\\
%
%
\Lambda =\ & \frac{m}{r^3} + \frac{2}{3} \tag{2}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
R_{33} =\ & \Lambda g_{33}
\nonumber\\
%
%
\Lambda =\ & \frac{m}{r^3} + \frac{2}{3} \tag{3}
\end{align}

Since $\Lambda_{(1)}$ is not the same with $\Lambda_{(2)}$ and $\Lambda_{(3)}$, then the metric is **NOT** Einstein. On the other hand, **the Scalar Ricci is constant**, thus the metric is supposed to be Einstein. And now I am confused.

Comment: Your metric does **not** satisfy $R_{ab}=kg_{ab}$. Any reason to expect it does? Can you cite some reference where it is claimed that it does?

Comment: The de Sitter Schwarzschild metric has a time component too. Any reason you are ignoring that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1, First, You should check if Your metric is vacuum solution of Einstein equation with non-zero cosmological constant $\Lambda$. Vanishing $\Lambda$ will give a trivial equality (if the metric is vacuum solution).

Generally, Einstein equation with zero matter tensor can be rewritten as [(Einstein metric)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_manifold)
$$
R_{\mu \nu}=\frac{2\Lambda}{d-2}g_{\mu\nu}
$$

2, Your metric (as I checked) is neither the solution of $d=3$ nor $d=4$ (with a constant time-time component) Einstein equation. So I think Your problem is here.

3, Your statement

> the Scalar Ricci is constant, thus the metric is supposed to be Einstein

is incorrect. "Scalar Ricci is constant" is only *necessary* condition of Einstein metric, not sufficient.